# centering on marker, Google maps api

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display a couple of markers on a Google map, and allow the user to center the map on a marker when they click that marker.

However, when the user clicks on any marker, the map always centers on the last marker I create in my code.

Here is the full code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 150),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34,-150);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title:'test' + 1
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());});

myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(20,-87);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title:'test' + 2
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());});

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Spent a while on this, consulting the Google maps api references, but just cannot figure out why it is not working.

Any insights appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Oh - I would be using my api code in place of MY_API_KEY, of course :)

Comment: Why are you using this approach?  You should store the latitude, longitude, and title in an array, and then use a for loop to add the data.  Otherwise, if you want to keep this approach, rename your second variable marker2 (or something like that) and add an event listener for marker2 (or whatever you name it).

Comment: Old question I know but I posted the same question here and then managed to solve it myself:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273835/google-maps-apis-clicking-marker-zooms-in-on-wrong-one

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() 
>       {
>           @Override
>           public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
>           {
>               int yMatrix = 200, xMatrix =40;
>
>               DisplayMetrics metrics1 = new DisplayMetrics();
>               getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics1);
>               switch(metrics1.densityDpi)
>               {
>               case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
>                   yMatrix = 80;
>                   xMatrix = 20;
>                   break;
>               case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
>                   yMatrix = 100;
>                   xMatrix = 25;
>                   break;
>               case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
>                   yMatrix = 150;
>                   xMatrix = 30;
>                   break;
>               case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
>                   yMatrix = 200;
>                   xMatrix = 40;
>                   break;
>               case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
>                   yMatrix = 200;
>                   xMatrix = 50;
>                   break;
>               }
>
>               Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();
>               LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
>               Point point = projection.toScreenLocation(latLng);
>               Point point2 = new Point(point.x+xMatrix,point.y-yMatrix);
>
>               LatLng point3 = projection.fromScreenLocation(point2);
>               CameraUpdate zoom1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point3);
>               mMap.animateCamera(zoom1);
>               marker.showInfoWindow();
>               return true;
>           }
>       });
> ```